# Error - git push heroku master

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, git, heroku

If you're attempting to help me, I really appreciate it. 
So when I write git push heroku master, it fails to parse, and before you spit at me and say 'READ OTHERS!!!!' I have. I've rewritten the package.JSON and used a validator. The strange thing is it always says line 9, column 3, every time I reformat the package.JSON, always line 9, column 3. I have changed over 5-7 times. I don't think my package.json is necessary as it always brings that error. 
But here it is anyway.

```
{
  "name": "vulture",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Vulture is a bot for discord.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.4.0",
    "npm": "5.4.0"
  },
  "author": "swagehsaan840#0336",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

A side note is changing it will *probably* give me the same error, but I never know, after using a validator and changing any times, it always says line 9, column 3. 
Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to write this way `package.json`

```
{
 "name": "vulture",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "vulture",
 "main": "index.js",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js",
  },
 "author": "vulture",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "node": "8.4.0",
   "npm": "5.4.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Line 9, Column 3 again! I told you, this will never work. Maybe heroku just hates me. Here is a picture of my error log.
https://vgy.me/3zCMjP.png

Comment: This `package.json` may give an error due to the trailing comma in you start script. Using a JSON formatter gives an error there.

Comment: i used a validator and it still gives line 9, column 3.
^.^ -- heroku just hates me and their staff said go try stack overflow  - what else is new

Answer (score 0):

add `Buildpacks` in heroku goto setting select add Buildpacks --> select nodejs